# Installing jQuery plugin into wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, forms, validation

I have a form that a user will fill out based on fitness test results i.e. push ups per minute, sit ups per minute, 2 mile run time etc. This form is submitting to a custom template page which also works fine. I would however like to use [this](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) jquery plugin to help me validate my form.

How do I add jQuery libraries like this into wordpress so i can validate my form

Comment: Please read about wp_enqueue_script http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: I've looked at the link you provided. I don't know where exactly to put the code

Answer (score 0):

Open your **functions.php** and add this code:

```
//ad our custom Jquery
 function init_js_scripts() {
if (!is_admin()) {
    wp_register_script('jquery', ('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js'), false, '');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

    // load a JS file from your  theme: js/theme.js
    //You will need to create js Folder and put your script in there...
    wp_enqueue_script('my_cool_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/cool_script.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
}
    }
    add_action('init', 'init_js_scripts');
```